# API Call within Laravel Controller

Tags: laravel, guzzle, looker

Is there a way to make an API call within a Laravel controller? so far I've been doing this w/out luck.  I really appreciate any help. I'm using Laravel 6.

[image: Laravel Auth Controller]

Comment: that seems fine, what problems are you having, any errors, logs etc?